# How to anonymize the data in SAS and R

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to anonymize the data and replace the client_rating with some random number (so I do not release the real data) but keep the original distribution and range of values

```
Client_Id    Key    Rating
001          111       2
001          112       3
001          113      10 
002          111       1
002          112       4
002          112       9
```

The range of values for

```
Key=111 is from 1 thru 4
key=112 is from 1 thru 5
key=113 is from 1 thru 11
```

I am looking for anonymizing the data using either SAS and/or R within specified ranges. I will prefer to keep the mean and standard deviation of the original data, but not only shuffle the original values. I am looking to randomly assign numbers between the range specified.

for instance Key 111 can have any rating between 1 and 4, although in the existing data, the rating values assigned is only 1 and 2.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to jitter or anonymize? It sounds more like anonymize to me.

Comment: what about `within(data, Rating2 <- ave(Rating, Key, FUN = function(x) x[sample.int(length(x))]))` which will randomly resample the rating by `Key`

Comment: Yes anonymize will be a better term for what I am looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Jittering is just adding random numbers to your data. You probably either want to add random numbers that came from a normal distribution or numbers that came from a uniform distribution. The `rnorm()` and `runif()` functions in R will return random numbers for you, and then you can simply add them to `Rating`. A step further might be to use `Rating` as the standard deviation in `rnorm()` so that every observation gets jittered proportional to its size.

Comment: What are you planning to use the data for? Do you need to maintain more than the distribution range, what about standard deviation? Or is the file solely to provide sample structure?

Comment: I would recommend restating your question as well, with more clarification of what you're looking for.

Comment: You realize with small N's per group, it will almost impossible to replicate the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

`proc sgplot` has a `jitter` option in SAS 9.4 M2.

```
proc sgplot data=have;
   scatter x=key y=rating / jitter jitterwidth=0.85;
run;
```

`jitterwidth` is defined as

> the width of the jitter space as a fraction of either the midpoint
>   spacing or of the minimal interval width.

[Link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/67909/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1lcbd3lhs3t3bn1jk6d8sjt2yqx.htm)

If you need to manually jitter, you can do so with a data step by simply increasing or decreasing the value by random small fractions. I would recommend using the `rand` function with a `uniform` argument. For example, the below code will randomly add or subtract a number between 0 and 1 from `client_rating`. This should, effectively, jitter the data in the `y` direction.  You can also do it in the `x` direction to add an additional dimension.

```
data want;
    set have;

    /* y jitter */
    if(rand('Uniform') > 0.5) then client_rating_jit = client_rating + rand('Uniform');
       else client_rating_jit = client_rating - rand('Uniform');

    /* optional: x jitter */
    if(rand('Uniform') > 0.5) then key_jit = key + rand('Uniform');
       else key_jit = key - rand('Uniform');

run;
```

If you need more or less jitter, you can change the min/max of the uniform distribution mathematically:

`min + (1+max - min)*rand('Uniform')`

Comment: `client_rating_jit = client rating + &factor.*(rand('Uniform')-0.5);`, where `&factor` determines how big of a jitter, should work for what you're trying to do there.  Avoids two random calls which is usually better for avoiding correlations.